# Infinite sum of non-negative terms is equal to the supremum of the set of all finite sums

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Prove that if $a_n \geq 0$, for all $n$, then
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n = \sup \bigg\{ \sum_{i \in A} a_i : A \subset \mathbb{N}, A \text{ finite} \bigg\}.$$

My general strategy right now is to prove $\geq$ and $\leq$, both directions.

I was able to prove $\geq$ (because the LHS is an infinite sum, while the RHS is finite, so an infinite sum must be greater or equal to a finite sum), but I can't get the $\leq$ direction.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Start by unfolding the _definition_ of the notation on the right, and recall that the limit of a non-decreasing sequence is the same as the supremum of its elements.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Say $s=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ and $\displaystyle S=\left\{\sum_{n\in F}a_n:F\in\mathscr P_{finite}(\Bbb N)\right\}$, so you want to show $s=\sup(S)$.

From what you say about the inequality $s\ge\sup(S)$ it seems clear you have the right idea; it could be much better phrased.

To show $s\le \sup(S)$, note first that it's enough to show that $$\alpha<\sup(S)\quad(\forall  {\alpha<s}).$$But saying something is less than the least upper bound says it is not an upper bound. So what you need to show is this:

> > If $\alpha<s$ there exists a finite $F\subset\Bbb N$ with $$\alpha<\sum_{n\in F}a_n.$$

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something. Since $s$ is an infinite sum, and $S$ is the set of finite sums, it seems like s is not in S, so I don't get how showing that $s < \alpha < \sup (S)$ is showing that something is less than the upper bound, because $s$ is not in the same set as $\sup (S)$?

Comment: @shiron No, $s$ is not in $S$. That has nothing to do with anything. An upper bound fora set $A$ need not be an element of $A$. By definition $\sup(S)$ is the **smallest** upper bound for $S$. So if we _assume_ $s<\sup(S)$ then $s$ is even smaller than the smallest upper bound, hence $s$ is not an upper bound for $S$. (Or: If $s$ was an upper bound for $S$ then $s<\sup(S)$ says that $\sup(S)$ is not the least upper bound, contradiction.)